# Plants name, help.

Tags: identification

[image]

Does anyone know what plant is that. That seems like a lanceolate leaves to me.

Comment: Lots of white fly, that is for sure.  Could you send a picture of the entire plant in its environment?  Where are you on this planet?  Tropical, subtropical?  Your plant zone?  Please, send more information.

Comment: Welcome! The tag on the question is "trees" but in the question you're calling it a plant. Would you be kind enough to clarify that? Also, answers to questions from @stormy and any others will help us help you! You can add more information and pictures using [edit]. Check out our [help] to learn about our unique site. [Ask] is a good place to start. If you have any problems using the site, leave a comment and someone will help you!! Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a dwarf bamboo of some variety.

Comment: Agree ,some bamboo. I have  a very similar one that has spread all over my yard.. Cutting it to grass height with the mower  does not stop it. I would hand pull it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd send a picture of bamboo leaves.  Bamboo is a monocot and monocots, grasses have parallel venation.  The veins in the leaves are parallel to the mid vein and to each other.  Dicots have venation similar to a bird's feather.

I am sorry, I am unable to see the venation of your leaves, really need to see the entire plant.  Is this a shrub, tree or herbaceous perennial?

[image: Leaves of a bamboo]

[image: bamboo leaves]

Answer (score 0):

Ginger 
Zingiber officinale

The photo is slightly grainy but the leaves should have "lines" along the leaf.